# Identifying triggers UniqueId that invoked during runtime

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I have a trigger created having value getUniqueId() which equals 33032101292973583 and it invokes mytrigfunction every 1 hour. I save 33032101292973583 value and a persons email id (example@it.com) in a sheet,

```
mytrigfunction()
{
during this function execution 
I compare 33032101292973583 from my sheet with current invoked trigger
if yes then send the mail to (example@it.com) person
otherwise
send mail to some other person (some@it.com) with some other trigger unique id matched
}
```

Comment: What's your question, that this isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your question is "can I compare the ID I extract from the event when the trigger fires with the one I got when I created the trigger?" the answer is yes, kind of! I've found that of the 19 digits you can only compare the first 14, the last 5 seem to be different so you need to take those off ?!

The event handler function called by the trigger will be passed an event, and one of its properties is the trigger's ID so I use this code to get the ID (the 14 characters that match the one returned by getUniqueId() and stored using the PropertiesService):

```
function triggerEventHander(event) {
  var eventTriggerId = event.triggerUid.toString().slice(0,14)
}
```

Comment: But how to extract ID? whats the code? How to get the ID

Comment: Thanks Andrew, after some dig, I managed to settle with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057177/google-app-script-trigger-id-format.

Comment: Nice find. It looks like we aren't the only ones banging our heads against this! So it's a rounding error of sorts. So are you finding that Eskay's answer works for you.